# Change of Parameters from surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Let p be a point of regular surface $S$,and let $X:U⊂R^2→S,Y:V⊂R^2→S$ be two parametrizations of S such that $p∈X(U)∩Y(U)=W$,then the "change of coordinates" $h=X^{-1}◦Y:Y^{-1}(W)→X^{-1}(W)$ is a diffeomorphism;that is,h is differentiable and has a differentiable inverse $h^{-1}$

On DoCarmo Differiential geometry,the proof says $X^{-1}$defined in an opensubset of $S$, and we do not yet know what is meant by a
differentiable function on $S$.What does it mean?Is it true that we cannot define $X^{-1}$?

My first intuition is that $X^{-1}$ is differentiable(because $X$ is differentiable) $Y$ is differentiable,so we apply the chain rule for map,so $h$ is also differentiable and $h^{-1}$ is also differentiable.Is it right?Well,I don't think so but I can't find where is wrong.(I suppose it may come from $X^{-1}$ that I can't figure it out)

—————————————————————————————
Appendix(The chain rule for maps):Let $F:U⊂R^n→R^m$,let$G:V⊂R^m→R^k$ be differentiable maps,where $U$ and $V$ are open sets,such that $F(U)⊂V$,then $G ◦F:U→R^k$ is a differentiable map.
(I think we can apply this rule.)

Appreciate your feedbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On DoCarmo Differiential geometry,the proof says $^{−1}$ defined in an open subset of $$, and we do not yet know what is meant by a
>   differentiable function on $$. What does it mean? Is it true that we
>   cannot define $^{−1}$?

In general, whenever we have an injective map like $X$, we can take the image of $X$, i.e., the set $A = X(U)$, and define $X^{-1}$ as a function from $A$ back to $U$: we say that $X^{-1}(p) = q$ if and only if $q = X(p)$. So we certainly can define $X^{-1}$ on some open set in $S$ -- we just take any open subset of $A$.

We don't know what's meant by a differentiable function because "differentiable on $S$" is going to be defined *via* the coordinate charts.

Finally, the map $h$, if you look at it carefully, is a map from one subset of $\Bbb R^2$ to another subset of $\Bbb R^2$, so we *do* know what it means for $h$ to be differentiable (from our multivariable calculus class). The tricky thing is that although $h$ is defined by composition, so that it's tempting to use the chain rule, the chain rule only applies when $h$ is a composition of two functions that are *known to be differentiable,* and which are probably (in the version you've seen in multivariable calculus) required to be functions defined on some open set in Euclidean space. So you cannot apply it here!

There's hope for the future though: very soon you'll get a version of the chain rule that applies to differentiable functions from manifolds to manifolds, and life will begin to seem normal again.

Comment: +1 very nice answer

Comment: I comprehend your words.But in the definition of regular surfaces,we believe X is differentiable and also it’s a homeomorphism that means X is a bijective map so we can define X^(-1).On the other hand,the regularity condition tells us that dX is differentiable and also it’s one-to-one,so I suppose X^(-1) is also differentiable.These conditions tempt me to use chain rules.I don’t my understanding is right or wrong.Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: $X$ is differentiable, and it's a homeomorphism *onto its image*. Think of the parameterization $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$ from the disk of radius $\frac12$ in the plane to the arctic region of the sphere (where $+z$ is "north"). This is a homeomorphism onto that polar cap, but *not* a homeomorphism between the disk and $\Bbb R^3$. As for $X^{-1}$ is also differentiable, you might want to think about the map $t \mapsto t^3$ from $\Bbb R$ to itself; it's a homeomorphism, it's differentiable, but its inverse is not. (Regularity, as you've guessed, is critical here).

Comment: The chain rule you know applies to functions from $\Bbb R^k$ to $\Bbb R^n$...but $X^{-1}$ is only defined on a subset of $S$ (in my example: on the polar cap). So the chain rule you know probably doesn't work for this function.

Comment: I suppose I’ve understood your words.Let me try generalizing your words.Firstly，$X^{-1}$can be not differentiable,but the chain rule requires a differentiable $X$.Moreover，even we can define a differentiable $X^{-1}$,but$X^{-1}$ is only defined on a subset of $S$,not the whole $S$,so if we really want to use the chain rule,the map has to be very very special.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. For the chain rule to apply at a point, you need only that a function is defined in an open neighborhood of that point, so the "subset of $S$ versus "all of $S$" distinction isn't the key. The important distinction is between "an open neighborhood in $S$" vs "an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$." The arctic isn't open in $\Bbb R^3$, but it IS an open subset of the sphere, because it's the intersection of an open set in $\Bbb R^3$ with the sphere. One example such open set is the open ball of radius $1/2$ about the point $(0, 0, \sqrt{3}/2)$, which meets $S^2$ in the arctic.

Comment: @JohnHughes Great explanations,thanks.

Comment: I think I’ve totally understood your words of explaining why we can’t use chain rules for map and also I’ve realized why we need to extend $X$ to a new map $F$. The proof seems to be more clear than I first met it.Thanks!